# MongoDB Readahead warning

Tags: linux, mongodb

I'm receiving this warning when starting my MongoDB shell:

> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten]
>
> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Readahead for
>   /data is set to 2048KB
>
> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten] ** We suggest setting it to
>   256KB (512 sectors) or less
>
> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten] **
>   http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/readahead

I've used:

> df /data

To find where the drive is that my data is mounted and subsequently used:

> sudo blockdev --setra 256 /dev/mapper/vg0-data

to set the readahead to the 256 that was specified. I've confirmed this has worked with:

> sudo blockdev --getra /dev/mapper/vg0-data

I'm still however getting the same error when starting my shell?

***UPDATE***

I've restarted the mongodb server instance and am still receiving this error.

***UPDATE 2***

My linux server is hosted on AWS and therefore uses virtual volumes. I have set the readahead value for all those volumes to 256 and still receive this error.

***UPDATE 3***

This is a blockdev --report of the Primary instance of MongoDB

```
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0      8589934592   /dev/xvda1
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh8
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh7
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh6
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh5
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh4
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh3
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh2
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh1
rw  4096   512  4096          0     42944430080   /dev/md127
rw  4096   512  4096          0     38646317056   /dev/dm-0
rw  4096   512  4096          0      2143289344   /dev/dm-1
rw  4096   512  4096          0      2143289344   /dev/dm-2
```

This is a blockdev --report of the Secondary instance of MongoDB

```
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0      8589934592   /dev/xvda1
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh8
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh7
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh6
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh5
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh4
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh3
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh2
rw   256   512  4096          0     10737418240   /dev/xvdh1
rw  4096   512  4096          0     42944430080   /dev/md127
rw  4096   512  4096          0     38646317056   /dev/dm-0
rw  4096   512  4096          0      2143289344   /dev/dm-1
rw  4096   512  4096          0      2143289344   /dev/dm-2
```

This is a blockdev --report of the Arbiter instance of MongoDB

```
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0      8589934592   /dev/xvda1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was to run `blockdev --setra` in a startup script. Every time the system reboots the read-ahead values revert back to default.

In my case I just figured out what my logical drives were with `blockdev --report`, I then run `blockdev --setra` on every drive in the "start" section of the MongoDB startup script in init.d.

Hope this helps anybody else having similar issues.

Comment: Does it have to be in startup script...would it work if I stop mongo...then blockdev --setra and the restart mongo........would that not work? Please tell me why?

Comment: It would until you restart your system. I think you'd agree that having to run blockdev --setra after every restart of your system is less than ideal.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="xvdb", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="xvdc", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a  /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="xvdd", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="xvde", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a   /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="dm-0", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="dm-1", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="dm-2", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
echo 'ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="md127", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="64"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
```

where KERNEL=="" is your HDD device

then on restart everything will be set properly

```
rw   256   512  4096          0     42949672960   /dev/xvda1
rw   128   512  4096          0    214748364800   /dev/xvdc
rw   128   512  4096          0    214748364800   /dev/xvde
rw   128   512  4096          0    214748364800   /dev/xvdd
rw   128   512  4096          0    214748364800   /dev/xvdb
rw   128   512  4096          0    429227769856   /dev/md127
rw   128   512  4096          0    343379279872   /dev/dm-0
rw   128   512  4096          0     42920312832   /dev/dm-1
rw   128   512  4096          0     42920312832   /dev/dm-2
```

Comment: remember that ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb} - is the value in Kb, so you need to divide by 2 the amount of blocks you desire for RAH

Answer (score 4):

modify readahead value inside to 128 on `/usr/lib/tuned/throughput-performance/tuned.conf`

on centos7

Comment: after that you should run: tuned-adm profile no-thp

Answer (score 3):

If the data files are in `/data` but those files are no on the device specified, setting the proper read ahead on `/dev/mapper/vg0-data` will have no effect.

The `blockdev` command should be run against the device /data is mounted from: `sudo blockdev --setra 256 /dev/<dev where data lives>`

Comment: So where the data lives would be the references to the drives inside /dev/. In my case /dev/sd1-8. I have set all the drives' readahead values to 256 and still no luck.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `blockdev --report`?

Answer (score -1):

Ive written an init script to set/unset this for me:

[readahead initscript](https://gist.github.com/mark-vandenbos/a979cb93977114406951c0a69f8ff378)

Comment: You've answered with a link which no longer exists

Comment: Broken link-only answer

Comment: fixed, sorry about that